# Error in consuming the API: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field networkTimeMs of type J in class Lcom/android/volley/NetworkResponse

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools

Below is the stack trace:

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field networkTimeMs of type J in class Lcom/android/volley/NetworkResponse; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.android.volley.NetworkResponse' appears in /data/app/mypackagename-ameeB7Iwb0Yz-sue9S-uWw==/base.apk!classes7.dex)

at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(Unknown Source:98)

Its working fine with one of my build variant (SIT),but something I gets this error.

Below are the things done.

- Cleared the gradle file
- Invalidate the cache and restart the studio.
- Rebuild the project.